# Using xsd 1.1 assert for range checks

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I have been given a task to generate an XSD file that validates fisheries data coming in xml files. The data involved list down all the fish that have been caught during a fishing trip (with all the details) in a fishing trip such as species_code, length, sex, etc. The first part of the validation is to check that the species_code is valid and I have done this check by listing all the valid sp_code in an enumeration and checking the sp_code against this list. 
Below is a catch from the xml file

```
  <CATCH>
    <CATCH_ID>1</CATCH_ID>
    <CATCH_DATE>2017-06-02T05:27:49Z</CATCH_DATE>
    <SP_CODE>ALB</SP_CODE>
    <LEN>103</LEN>
    <SEX_CODE>U</SEX_CODE>
    <LAT>-2033.126</LAT>
    <LON>+17602.598</LON>
  <CATCH>
```

First part that I have managed to do is to check if SP_CODE entered is valid:

```
        <xs:element name="CATCH" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="SP_CODE" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="SP_ENUM">
                                <xs:assertion/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="LEN" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="SP_ENUM">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="ALB"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="ALO"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="ALX"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="BAR"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="BET"/>
    </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

However, there is a second part which is kind of messing up my head(new to this xsd validations. The problem is depending on the species_code, there is a length range eg if sp_code is BET--for big eye tuna then LENGTH should be in range 50-200 cm, else if SP_CODE is ALB--for albacore then LENGTH should be in range 50-140 cm, etc. That is a simple business rule I would like to test for in my xsd. I am doing some searching and is showing me that xsd 1.1 assertions is one way but just not clear on how it can be used to solve this problem. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You have a choice of writing one complex assertion or lots of little assertions (each of which must be true). I would use the latter approach because it's easier to see what's wrong if the assertion fails. Typical assertions might be

```
<xs:assert test="if (SP_CODE eq 'ALB') then (LEN ge 50) else true()"/>
<xs:assert test="if (SP_CODE eq 'ALB') then (LEN le 250) else true()"/>
```

These elements should appear as children of the `<xs:element name="CATCH">`, after the `<xs:complexType>`. They don't belong with the SP_CODE, as in your sample, because they don't affect what is a valid SP_CODE, only what is a valid CATCH.

The `else true()` is tedious boilerplate needed to satisfy the XPath syntax rules. It basically says that if the "if" condition doesn't apply, then the assertion imposes no constraints.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the prompt response. I can see the logic is working so I can expand this for the other species also. It is also giving me an error when a catch does not have a length element(meaning some fish are not measured) making this element an optional I suppose, so for such case, how can I code to handle this.

Comment: You could expand the condition to` if (SP_CODE eq 'ALB' and exists(LEN)) then (LEN ge 50) else true()` or you could write `if (SP_CODE eq 'ALB') then not(LEN lt 50) else true()`. (Value comparisons in XPath are false if one operand is empty).